# how to use Java/Android string formatting on <string-array>

Tags: java, android, string-formatting

How can is use string formatting on the 

`<string-array><item>` - resource in Android?

Should i do it like in the following example(and how should i do it if yes)...

```
<string-array name="notification-msgs">
   <item>%s sent you a message.</item>
   <item>%s answered to your Story</item>
</string-array>
```

or what kind of technique is common to use in this case?
I only know how to Format string resources.(with `getString(R.id.mystring,replacevalue)`)
Thanks for any help!
**EDIT:**

- I tried to use getStringArray(), but this method does not accept more then one argument, which just is an Array-Ressource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct way provided by Android to achieve this. Best you can do is:

`String.format(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.notification-msgs)[0], "Someone")`

Comment: In kotlin you can use `format` method as extension function, like: ```getResources().getStringArray(R.array.notification-msgs)[0].format("Someone")```

Answer (score 0):

Android supports formatting with `getString(String str,Object... args)`. [Link here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getString(int,%20java.lang.Object...))
Or you can wrap formatting with a method.

```
public static String formatString(String pure,Object... args){
     return String.format(pure,args);
}
//Or 
public static String formatString(int id,Context context,Object... args){
     String pure = context.getString(id);
     return String.format(pure,args);
}
```

I personally prefer second approach, it is easy to mutable in the future.

Comment: As I understand your answer, directly formatting string-array-items is not possible? (Thanks for the answer btw)
And also I know how to format single strings in java and android, but I have the described problem with the string-array resource, where formatting strings from <item> seems to be impossible?!

Comment: Yes it is not possible, but you can use loops to format array as the same way